# Why does validation of DTD gives me the error "A ')' is required in the declaration of element type "Invoice"?

Tags: xml, validation, dtd

I am writing a DTD to my XML file. I get this same error "A ')' is required in the declaration of element type "Invoice"" on the element "Invoice". My DTD matches my XML, names are correct, order of elements is correct. Any help would be appreciated. Below are my DTD and XML files.

I've tried reordering the elements of the DTD, looked at my XML to try and find a mistake there, but nothing  seems to work.

```
<!ELEMENT InvoiceList (Invoice*) >
<!ELEMENT Invoice (Client, Company, TaxNumber|USt-IdNr, ServicesList, Date, Amount, BankAccount) >
<!ATTLIST Invoice NumberOfInvoice CDATA #IMPLIED>

<!ELEMENT Client (Name, Address)>
<!ELEMENT Name (#PCDATA) >

<!ELEMENT Address (Street, ZipCode, City) >

<!ELEMENT Street (Name, Number) >
<!ELEMENT Number (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT ZipCode (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT City (#PCDATA) >

<!ELEMENT Company (Name, Address) >
<!ELEMENT TaxNumber (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT USt-IdNr (#PCDATA) >

<!ELEMENT ServiceList (Service) >
<!ELEMENT Service (Position, Name, MwSt, Quantity, SinglePrice, TotalPrice) >
<!ATTLIST Service Date CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ELEMENT Position (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT MwSt (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT Quantity (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT SinglePrice (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT TotalPrice (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT Date (#PCDATA) >

<!ELEMENT Amount (Total|Brutto, Netto, MwSt) >
<!ELEMENT Total (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT Brutto (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT Netto (#PCDATA) >

<!ELEMENT BankAccount (Name, Bank, BLZ, AccountNumber) >
<!ELEMENT Bank (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT BLZ (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT AccountNumber (#PCDATA) >

<InvoiceList>
<Invoice NumberOfInvoice="657321">
        <Client>
            <Name>Frau Sybille Sonder-Sutterrau</Name>
            <Address>
                <Street>
                    <Name>Am Süttelbach</Name>
                    <Number>17</Number> 
                </Street>
                <ZipCode>77070</ZipCode>
                <City>Siedelsuderstadt</City>
            </Address>
        </Client>
        <Company>
            <Name>Kleintier Meier GmbH</Name>
            <Address>
                <Street>
                    <Name>Meierring</Name>
                    <Number>3</Number> 
                </Street>
                <ZipCode>81828</ZipCode>
                <City>Machthausen</City>
            </Address>
            <ContactInformation>
                <PhoneNumber>0777/987987</PhoneNumber>
                <Fax>0777/987789</Fax>
                <EMail>klein.meier@tiere.de</EMail>
            </ContactInformation>
        </Company> 
        <TaxNumber>88 123/8282 2</TaxNumber>
        <ServicesList>
            <Service Date="1.1.2017">
                <Position>1</Position>
                <Name>Antike Holzwürmer</Name>
                <MwSt>19%</MwSt>
                <Quantity>100</Quantity>
                <SinglePrice>1,50</SinglePrice>
                <TotalPrice>150,00</TotalPrice>
            </Service>
            <Service Date="12.1.2017">
                <Position>2</Position>
                <Name>Holzwurmfutter</Name>
                <MwSt>19%</MwSt>
                <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                <SinglePrice>34,45</SinglePrice>
                <TotalPrice>34,45</TotalPrice>
            </Service>
            <Service Date="12.1.2017">
                <Position>3</Position>
                <Name>Steinlaus, Petrophaga lorioti</Name>
                <MwSt>19%</MwSt>
                <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                <SinglePrice>777,77</SinglePrice>
                <TotalPrice>777,77</TotalPrice>
            </Service>
        </ServicesList>
        <Date>15.1.2017</Date>
        <Amount>
            <Brutto>962,22</Brutto>
            <Netto>808,59</Netto>
            <Mwst>153,63</Mwst> 
        </Amount>
        <BankAccount>
            <Name>Kleintier Meier</Name>
            <Bank>Sparkasse Karlsruhe</Bank>
            <BLZ>66050101</BLZ>
            <AccountNumber>987654321</AccountNumber>
        </BankAccount>
    </Invoice>
```

I am using Eclipse to validate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `|` you should wrap that group in parentheses.

You should update both `Invoice` and `Amount` declarations...

```
<!ELEMENT Invoice (Client, Company, (TaxNumber|USt-IdNr), ServicesList, Date, Amount, BankAccount) >
```

and

```
<!ELEMENT Amount ((Total|Brutto), Netto, MwSt) >
```

After those changes your DTD will be valid but perhaps not correct; your XML still won't validate as there are still a few issues...

- `ContactInformation` isn't allowed as a child of `Company` (and `ContactInformation` and it's children (`PhoneNumber`, `Fax`, and `EMail`) aren't declared at all in the DTD)
- The element `ServicesList` isn't declared in the DTD. `ServiceList` is declared though so you probably just missed the `s` in the name of the declaration.
- You use `Mwst` in the XML but in the DTD it's declared `MwSt` (pay attention to case).